# getting error while using sqoop 1.4.5 and hadoop 2.41

Tags: java, hadoop, import, sqoop

While importing data from sqoop 1.4.5, I am getting below error

```
15/04/30 16:15:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1430385162985_0014
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:53)
```

I am using hadoop 2.4.1 with java version "1.7.0_75".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of error usually comes when there is a version conflict,So please make sure your Sqoop version is compatible with your Hadoop distribution. And in case if you are using some third party connector for importing data, it should also be compatible with your sqoop version.
I am using sqoop 1.4.5 with hadoop version 2.4.0 for importing data from various RDBMS (MYSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Netezza, Teradata, DB2). It works for me.

Comment: I am using sqoop 1.4.5 and hadoop 2.4.1 on ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)? please help

Comment: You are trying to import data from which RDBMS? Any connector you are using for import? If yes, then please share the version.

Comment: connector mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar and mysql version  5.5.41

Comment: Can you please check the user has proper permissions on hadoop and sqoop folder along with its sub-directories.  Just for testing purpose give 777 permissions to the user and then try executing sqoop import command.

Comment: And if there is no permission issue, then you can give a try with hadoop 2.4.0 version.

Comment: Reena:- I am still getting issue with the lower version of hadoop 2.4.0

Comment: can you please help me ?

Comment: Have you tried with hadoop 2.4.0 version and sqoop 1.4.5? I am using this version, and not facing any such error.

Comment: Yes, I used both the version and still getting issue. Is 64-bit os or mysql version was the issue ?

Comment: My MYSQL version is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40 and the jdbc jar version is mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar. I am running it on 64 bit OS

Comment: Finally it is resolved and you are right issue was with the version, I used hadoop-1.2.1 and sqoop 1.4.5 it works fine . thanks

Comment: cool :) If my suggestions helped you in solving the issue, can you please upvote my answer :)

Comment: can i have your email Id , I have few concern regarding hadoop. If it is possible ?